# Simulate $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rather easy question:

Is it possible to “send” in the code **(invisible to the user)** a false $(document).ready() in Jquery?

What I want to do is to force all of my Jquery – Code to be ready for action after my Ajax call…
I know of the .on() function but it can’t trigger all of my code on the same time other that while loading the main content……

Thank you for your help

ps. I know I didn't post a lot for this question but it still bugs me...
pps. Sorry for my english

Comment: So, you want your code to be called once your AJAX call is done?

Comment: document ready is just that, it's triggered once, when the document is ready, not after an ajax call. You should learn to use the callbacks provided for the ajax methods.

Answer (score 3):

A pattern like this could work:

```
function init() {
    //do whatever
}

$(document).ready(init);

$.ajax({...}).done(init);
```

Comment: Stick an event handler in `init`, and you have a nightmare !

Comment: True, you'd have to be careful about what runs more than once

Comment: Interesting concept, but struggling to think of a use case for this (Despite the OP)

Comment: I've used a similar pattern with an asp.net `UpdatePanel`, which basically replaces all the html inside the control when it updates.

Comment: so all my code would go in to the init function or the init function triggers all code - right?

Comment: If you are sure you want everything in your `$(document).ready()` handler to run every time the ajax call finishes, then you'd just move all your `$(document).ready()` code to the `init` function.

Comment: You could also break your code out into to methods . . . a "do once" method and a "do more than once" method.  Then you could call both on `$(document).ready()` and only the second one when your Ajax finishes.

Comment: talemyn sorry to ask but what is a "do once" method or a "do more than once" method??

Comment: @adho12 If you have some things that need to happen only once when the DOM is ready and other things that need to happen after each ajax request, you could put those things in different functions, then call both on DOM ready, but only the "do more than once" function when ajax calls finish.

Answer (score 3):

You can do your event handling after ajax complete using [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

*"Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time."*

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    //event handling
});
```